# Constructing a back-end suitable for app and web interface

Tags: rest, api, architecture

Let's suppose I was going to design a platform like [Airbnb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbnb). They have a website as well as native apps on various mobile platforms.

I've been researching app design, and from what I've gathered, the most effective way to do this is to build an API for the back-end, like a REST API using something like node.js, and SQL or mongoDB. The font-end would then be developed natively on each platform which makes calls to the API endpoints to display and update data. This design sounds like it works great for mobile development, but what would be the best way to construct a website that uses the same API?

There are three approaches I can think of:

1. Use something completely client-side like AangularJS to create a single-page application front end which ties directly into the REST API back-end. This seems OK, but I don't really like the idea of a single-page application and would prefer a more traditional approach
2. Create a normal web application (in PHP, python, node.js, etc), but rather than tying the data to a typical back end like mySQL, it would basically act as an interface to the REST API. For example when you visit `www.example.com/video/3` the server would then call the corresponding REST endpoint (ie `api.example.com/video/3/show`) and render the HTML for the user. This seems like kind of a messy approach, especially since most web frameworks are designed to work with a SQL backend.
3. Tie the web interface in directly in with the REST api. For example, The endpoint `example.com/video/3/show` can return both html or json depending on the HTTP headers. The advantage is that you can share most of your code, however the code would become more complex and you can't decouple your web interface from the API.

What is the best approach for this situation? Do you choose to completely decouple the web application from the REST API? If so, how do you elegantly interface between the two? Or do you choose to merge the REST API and web interface into one code base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's a usually a prefered way but one should have a good command of SPA.
2. Adds a redundant layer from performance perspective. You will basically make twice more requests all the time.
3. This might work with super simple UI, when it's just a matter of serializing your REST API result into different formats but I believe you want rich UI and going this way will be a nightmare from both implementation and maintainance perspective.

SUGGESTED SOLUTION:
Extract your core logic. Put it into a separate project/assembly and reuse it both in your REST API and UI. This way you will be able to reuse the business logic which is the same both for UI and REST API and keep the representation stuff separately which is different for UI and REST API.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Both the first and the second option seem reasonable to me, in the sense that there are certain advantages in decoupling the backend API from the clients (including your web site). For example, you could have dedicated teams per each project, if there's a bug on the web/api you'd only have to release that project, and not both.

Say you're going public with your API. If you're releasing a version that breaks backwards compatibility, with a decoupled web app you'd be able to detect that earlier (say staging environment, given you're developing both in-house). However, if they were tightly coupled they'd probably work just fine, and you'll find out you've broken the other clients only once you release in production.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the first option is preferable one as a generic approach. SPA first load delay problem can be resolved with server side rendering technique.

For second option you will have to face scalability, cpu performance, user session(not on rest api of course because should be stateless), caching issues both on your rest api services and normal website node instances (maybe caching not in all the cases). In most of the cases this intermediate backend layer is just unnecessary, there is not any technical limitation for doing all the stuff in the recent versions of browsers.

The third option violates the separation of concerns, in your case presentational from data models/bussines logic.